# How to emit light from plane in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to achieve somewhat similar to this
http://groovemechanic.net/three.js.release/examples/#webgl_lights_rectarealight
This example was using AreaLight from Threejs which is not there in current version. I tried the code from the older version here 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r64/src/lights/AreaLight.js
but no luck.
Can anyone help me how to achieve this with current version?

Comment: Maybe this could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021264/improved-area-lighting-in-webgl-threejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you were looking at is still a bit of a work-in-progress. It was supposed to land in the three.js main-repository soon, but as of now, the only way to get this is via this branch: https://github.com/abelnation/three.js/tree/rect-area-light-with-ltc-approximation

See the pull-request here for updates on this topic: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/9234

Comment: can you point me html and js of it, I am looking the `example` directory in `rect-area-light-with-ltc-approximation` branch , but can't find it.

Comment: you can check the code on the example itself via firebug or similar ;)

Comment: I am asking about the url for code it-self, as I can't found code in that branch.

Comment: here would be the html-file for the example you posted: https://github.com/abelnation/three.js/blob/rect-area-light-with-ltc-approximation/examples/webgl_lights_rectarealight.html